# What is "machullah" in Stanley G. Weinbaum's short story Graph?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, stanley-g-weinbaum

Nothing specific can be said from the context and only one thing came up in my google search. I know it's a name, and it's probably Arabic in origin. But it just doesn't add up to the story really. It's in the last sentence of the following paragraph:

> "You doctors," continued Levinson, "spend your efforts treating symptoms instead of causes. Because I am tired, I must go somewhere and rest; because I can't sleep, I must get out somewhere and exercise; because I have no appetite, I must go away from my business! Why don't you find why I am tired, and can't sleep or eat? I should run my business like that and in a year I'd be broke—machullah!"

I only found it on a thread about favorite words (not poker related words) in a poker forum:

> "I've always heard it pronounced gunef or even ganef and in my experience it's meaning is more angle-shooter than out and out crook although I have certainly heard it used in the context of a guy who's business went "machullah" or busto and had all of his property in his wife's name."

So I guess it's something about bankruptcy?

I'm translating this story and really need to know its exact meaning and what language it is from. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. The word "machullah" has Jewish origins and connotes bankruptcy. Here is a quote from Hearst's magazine Vol 37:

> "Mr. Raynor," said Benno, impressively, "I'm what they call in Jewish,
>   machullah. It's like broke and busted only it's worse.

Also, consider the following excerpt from *The Jew in Old American Folklore*:

> In addition, peculiar language humor about failure is created. An
>   example is this late (1885) report from the West Coast forwarded to
>   the East and adorned with a whole row of names: "Have we a holiday
>   called 'Machullah?' I ask because there are a number of stores closed,
>   and if anyone is asked for the reason, the answer is 'Machullah,.'

Answer (score -1):

So I found out the meaning, 'going machullah' means 'going bankrupt'.

Comment: Please can you [edit] to add some support for this answer, e.g. saying *where* you found out the meaning? It's good to know that you managed to solve your question, but it's even better if this Q&A serves a purpose for future readers, adding to the larger repository of knowledge by being *verifiably* correct.